# R equivalent of MATLAB's filter function

Tags: r, matlab, signal-processing, waveform

I'm adapting MATLAB code to R and trying to generate a waveform using ARMA formula. Is there a simple R equivalent function for MATLAB's `filter` to take AR/MA coefficients to build a waveform?

```
npts = 100;
a = [1 0.6]; % AR coeffs
b = [1 0.25 3]; % MA coeffs
e = randn(npts,1); % generate gaussian white noise
waveform = filter(b,a,e); % generate waveform
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm can't you achieve that with [`filter`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/signal/html/filter.html) function in the package [signal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/index.html) ?

```
require(signal)
a = c(1,0.6)
b = c(1,0.25,3)
e = rnorm(100)
waveform = filter(b,a,e)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you can do this usring `arima.sim`, e.g.

```
arima.sim(npts, model=list(ar=a, ma=b), rand.gen=rnorm)
```

Note that the model is checked for stationarity and the model you have above is not stationary. If you want something integrated you can specify the order of integration in the model.

Comment: What would the appropriate order be for this model?

Comment: What if he is using non-synthetic data?