# R equivalent of MATLAB's wavedec and waverec function

Tags: r, matlab, time-series, signal-processing, wavelet

Im currently adapting matlab Code to R. Is there a function for a multilevel one-dimensional wavelet analysis using a specific wavelet?
In matlab it would be something like this:

```
[WaveletDecompositionVector BookkeepingVector] = wavedec(TimeSeries,levels,waveletName)
```

and the back transformation

```
 FilteredTS =waverec(WaveletDecompositionVector,BookkeepingVector,waveletName);
```

Comment: You need to describe what you want to achieve and what you've tried too, not just "here's something in language X, what is it in language Y".

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying the question enough: analogously to the Fourier approach but with a different function instead of a sinus function I want to filter (high pass, low pass or otherwise specified) my time series with a predefined function like Haar wavelett. For that I require a spectral decomposition (first line of code) than I would like to inspect the Power spectrum and choose the right frequencies. If I choose all frequencies I could appy the second line in my example and get approximately my time series back

Comment: @Wolfie: If I google some specific problem, I find solutions helpful like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048285/r-equivalent-of-matlabs-filter-function so I though this page would be similar helpful for other folks

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify your question, in future try to use the "edit" button under the question if you're adding lots of new information and links. Hopefully a better structured question will find your answer